# What's the idiomatic way to initialize a eigen dense column major matrix row wise from three column vectors

Tags: c++, matrix, initialization, eigen, eigen3

I'm wondering if there's a idiomatic way to initialize a eigen dense column major matrix row wise from three column vectors.

The following approaches ([godbolt them here](https://godbolt.org/z/xaKneGch4)) came into my mind, but i'm unsure if there's a preferred one and if it would make a difference in unoptimised builds, which, besides readability, is my main concern:

```
const Eigen::Vector3d x = Eigen::Vector3d::Random();
const Eigen::Vector3d y = Eigen::Vector3d::Random();
const Eigen::Vector3d z = Eigen::Vector3d::Random();

Eigen::Matrix3d mat1;
mat1 << x, y, z;
mat1.transposeInPlace();

Eigen::Matrix3d mat2;
mat2.row(0) << x.transpose();
mat2.row(1) << y.transpose();
mat2.row(2) << z.transpose();

Eigen::Matrix3d mat3;
mat3 << x.transpose(), y.transpose(), z.transpose();

Eigen::Matrix3d mat4;
mat4 << x[0], x[1], x[2], y[0], y[1], y[2], z[0], z[1], z[2];
```

Comment: I feel this is a matter of taste. I prefer the second of your three approaches. As you explicitly fill contra the storage order (filling a column major matrix with rows) I wouldn't expect any algorithm to work particularly fast, optimized or not.

Comment: Oh, reason for my opinion: The second one feels most explicit to me and I think everyone would understand it, even people not very familiar with Eigen.

Comment: Another alternative would be to use `Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3, Eigen::RowMajor>> map(mat.data())`. You can then just do `map << x, y, z`.

Comment: @dtell: That is clever! Although definitely not easily understood, especially for code readers not very familiar with eigen.